# how to get selected item in pyqt Qmenu

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

is there any way to get the selected item in a qmenu ? 
i want to bind all items in that list to one function and get the item once user click it .
i've been looking for a way to get the item's label or index for 3 days , but couldn't find it .
any ideas ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with signals.

Connect all [`triggered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#triggered) slots of your menu items to your function. Then, in this function, use the static function [`QObject::sender`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) to retrieve the menu item which has sent the signal.